# Grouping a grouped dataframe in a nested loop

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a scenario where I have to group a dataframe by a column and again group the resulting dataframe using a different column.  The reason I am iteratively grouping is because its easier for me to sack the results to a different dataframe. So the way I am trying to do is

```
g=df.groupby(col1):
for a,b in g:
    for c,d in b.groupby(col2):
```

When I try to do the above I am getting a None value in c instead of value associated with col2. What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: kindly share the source dataframe, as well as the expected output. nesting a groupby within a groupby does not seem efficient ... there might be a better way

Comment: Sadly , I cant share the actual dataframe as its proprietary data.

Comment: Make a dataframe with random data. We don't need to see the real data, just your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can't know with what you've given us, but your code should work fine... it does for me.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'EmployeeNo':[11111,11112,11113,11115,11116,11128],
                   'OutletName':['Outlet1', 'Outlet2', 'Outlet3','Outlet4', 'Outlet5','Outlet6'],
                   'EmployeeName':['John','Tom','Bob','Sam', 'Sean', 'Zac'],
                   'TargetAmount':[1000,500,400,500,300,800]})
g=df.groupby('OutletName')
for a,b in g:
    for c,d in b.groupby('EmployeeName'):
        print(c)
```

Output:

```
John
Tom
Bob
Sam
Sean
Zac
```